# How to use AWS CodePipeline to control scheduled EC2

Tags: aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I have created an AWS codepipeline to deploy code to EC2. the codepipeline has stages including source (from s3), codedeploy_to_test, approval, codedeploy_to_prod, etc. but the EC2 to be deployed only run a few hours like 7am-9pm every day. They stop at other time.

The codepipeline is started by a cloudwatch whenever code is committed to the s3.

How do I enhance the codepipeline so that it deploys code to the EC2 only btw. 7am-9pm, Other time it waits or ignores the change of source(s3)?

I am thinking maybe I can do sth. before each codedeploy so that if the time is 7am-9pm, go ahead, otherwise, do nothing. but I do not know what I can do to achieve that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CodePipeline does not currently have built-in support for this, however it's possible to use a Lambda function combined with either an approval actions or stage transitions to do this.

Here's an example of a Lambda function which will automatically approve a manual approval action during certain hours: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-codepipeline-time-windows

Comment: TimB: thanks, currently my codepipeline invoke a lambda to start EC2 before codedeploy and then invoke another lambda to stopEC2 after codedeploy. it works except I think if two code commit almost the same time, that may lead to some problem. because the first code complete which invoke EC2 to stop while the second code is still being deployed. I am going to use dynamodb to resolve this issue.